# PHP password_hash not working across browsers or machines and returning null

Tags: php, sql, password-hash

`PHP Version: 7.4`

I'm using `password_hash` and I'm having a peculiar problem. My code works perfectly for me, I'm able to sign in to my website without any problems using Chrome. However, another person trying to sign in keeps getting an incorrect password error using Chrome, so I then tried signing in in another browser and I started getting the same error.

I've pinpointed the problem to the use of `password_hash` and `password_verify` which are returning null and false respectively. `password_verify` is returning false because it's comparing a null string against the valid password string in the database.

The password in the database looks similar to this: `$2y$10$pH87se8G0fP9bE/s6RtPReVDqn2qOqs0CA8BE90DLCD9RLtLdG74e`.

My code is as follows:

Password Creation (Only used on register.php):

```
$options = [ // pass hash options
    'cost' => 14,
];
$pass = password_hash(base64_encode(hash("sha512", strval($_POST['password']), true), PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options));
```

Password Verification (used on signin.php):

```
if(!password_verify(base64_encode(hash("sha512", strval($_POST['password']), true)), $fetch['password'])) {
```

As I said, this works perfectly for me in Chrome but not in any other browser, and this does not work for anybody else on any browser.

I also use this system on other websites and have never had issues before so I have no idea why I'm experiencing this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd be looking at the form method attribute and the submitted names/value pairs.

Comment: Your parentheses are misplaced, you're passing 3 args to `base64_encode` instead of `password_hash`... Also you really don't need all that manual encoding stuff to encode/verify a password, [just passing the password directly to `password_*` functions should be enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords).

Comment: jeff Thanks for your input. The form method and name/value pairs are correct though, it's one of the things I triple checked before posting.

@Jeto Leaving out the manual encoding seems to have worked for me across all browsers, just waiting for one of my users to test it to see if it works for them and if it does, I'll post it as the answer. Thank you!

brombeer Thanks for your input. I know that the front-end and back-end have little to nothing to do with each other, that's why I was so confused. In a way though, you were right, my PHP was faulty. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing the manual encoding as suggested by @Jeto ([Jeto's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941515/php-password-hash-not-working-across-browsers-or-machines-and-returning-null#comment118328289_66941515)).

My code now looks as so:

```
password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

password_verify($_POST['password'], $fetch['password'])
```

The issue I had was still unusual because it sometimes worked as it was, but going back to basics solved the problem (as it so often does).

Thanks Jeto.